# How to render images on html from URL in slider using Bootstrap

Tags: java, html, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am developing a little web application using Spring and I can't understand how to display images in slider

I get the id from @PathVariable after that I am trying to get N-images from DB table 'photos' then display image in html(there is I used Bootstrap 4) but I only display one image(first) from N-images in DB

```
     @GetMapping("/post/{id}/post-image")
public void showImageFromDB(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    List<Photo> photos = photoService.getPhotos(id);
    if (photos != null) {
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        for (Photo photo : photos) {
            try {
                response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                byte[] image = photo.getPhoto();
                outputStream.write(image);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
             <div>
                 <img class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" th:src="@{'/post/' + ${post.id} + '/post-image'}" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/../../images/no-image.png'">
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
     </a>
 </div>
```

What I didn't understand and how I should process those stream bites ?

(p.s. excuse me for my grammar)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change your carousel to have multiple images.  On your `post` object, you should add an `int images` that contains a count of how many images for that post.  Then change the carousel to loop over your images by adding a `th:each` to the `div.carousel-item`:

```
<div class="carousel-item" th:classappend="${status.first} ? 'active'" th:each="i, status: ${#numbers.sequence(0, post.images - 1)}">
    <div>
        <img   class="card-img-top"
               alt="Card image"
               th:src="@{/post/{id}/post-image/{image}(id=${post.id},image=${i})}"
               onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/../../images/no-image.png'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, you need to change the controller that outputs an image to output the correct image, like this:

```
@GetMapping("/post/{id}/post-image/${image}")
public void showImageFromDB(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @PathVariable("image") int image, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    List<Photo> photos = photoService.getPhotos(id);
    if (photos != null) {
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        Photo photo = photos.get(image);
        try {
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            byte[] image = photo.getPhoto();
            outputStream.write(image);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```